# Selenium 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

So I'm using python and selenium to scrape the product titles on a sephora [page](https://www.sephora.com/ca/en/shop/face-makeup).

```
url = 'https://www.sephora.com/ca/en/shop/face-makeup'

driver.get(url)  
time.sleep(2)
   
browser = scrollDown(driver, 20)

# this selected the div for every product on the page
products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('css-79elbk')

for product in products:
    title = product.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/main/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
    print(title)
```

The problem is that when I run it I get `Line 48: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`. The title is in a span that is nested in a div. I've tried this on a normal div with text inside and it scrapes it no problem.

Comment: Note that the function you are using finds element**s** by xpath (note the "s" in `find_elements_by_xpath`). The function returns a list, not a single object.

Comment: @ShaneBishop that got rid of the error I was mentioning but now it just returns the first product price x amount of products on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appear because this line:

```
.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/main/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[4]/span[2]').text
```

The above return a list.

`.text` method utilize to `.find_element_*` (without **s**)

But in simple you can scrape the title by css selector with this value : `div[data-comp="ProductDisplayName "] span[data-at="sku_item_name"]`

Try following code:

```
url = 'https://www.sephora.com/ca/en/shop/face-makeup'

driver.get(url)  
time.sleep(2)
   
browser = scrollDown(driver, 20)

titles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[data-comp="ProductDisplayName "] span[data-at="sku_item_name"]')
for title in titles:
    print(title.text)
```

To scrape the brand, you only change selector to be : `div[data-comp="ProductDisplayName "] span[data-at="sku_item_brand"]`

Comment: thank you! I didn't even know you could scrape with data attributes.